# Thoughts on Implementing custom Android ArrayAdapter for multiple views?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a tabbed Android application with ListViews in two different tabs.  I have a custom ArrayAdapter (myAdap) which I'd like to make usable for both tabs. The thing is, each tab needs to maintain a checkbox state for each item in it's respective listview. Two tabs, two ListViews, two different sets of checked list items. Just making a copy of myAdap for the second ListView (tab) and renaming it would get me on my way but then I end up copying/pasting changes from one file to the other just to keep them up-to-date. I think it would be more efficient to modify myAdap to accept another parameter such as the backing array for checkbox state in each listview. Then, I could just instantiate myAdap with something like `myadapter = new myAdap (this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, backingArrayList);` Another thought I had was to implement the onCheckChange() listener in the parent class and pass the listener to myAdap instead. This would keep the backing arrays in their respective classes, but not so sure this is the best route to go either. Is there another way I'm not thinking of here?

Comment: It's really hard to give a concrete answer to theoretical questions like this, but it seems like you should simply create two objects of the same class, one per tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instantiate 2 objects of your adapter

```
myadapterForTab1 = new myAdap (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, backingArrayList);
myadapterForTab2 = new myAdap (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, backingArrayList);
```

Comment: Interesting. I ended up doing this and realized I needed to pass the ArrayList by reference in order to make it work. I don't recall ever doing this before and didn't know if it would work so just passed in the ArrayList. It seems to have worked although conspicuous. Apparently Java only passes primitive types by value, and Objects are passed as a references.